# How does javax.ejb.TimerService know which bean to call?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

How does [javax.ejb.TimerService](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TimerService.html) (Glassfish 3.1.2.2) know which bean to execute?

In the [Java EE 6 tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) we learn that we can define timer callbacks in an enterprise bean:

```
@Timeout
public void timeout(Timer timer) {
    System.out.println("TimerBean: timeout occurred");
}
```

Then we can schedule programmatic timers like this:

```
@Resource
TimerService timerService;
...
// Sets a programmatic timer that will expire in 1 minute (6,000 milliseconds):
long duration = 6000;
Timer timer = timerService.createSingleActionTimer(duration, new TimerConfig());
```

How does the TimeService know which *bean* to call? There can only be one annotated method in the bean, but how does it know which bean to call? `this` is not a parameter of `createSingleActionTimer`.

Comment: I'm checking out the Glassfish source code right now to look at the `TimerService` implementation, but this seems like an interesting question to me so I'll share it here for expert insight.

Comment: On further thought it's probably getting the object reference during `@Resource` injection from the [InjectionPoint](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/injection.html#d0e1624) object. I'll see if I can find it in the source code, if this checkout ever finishes.

Comment: The origin story is long and boring, but it boils down to this: in a DI container, nothing is truly hidden, and nothing is as it seems. The container has more than a few mechanisms for injection and all of them are context-aware. Everything in the container knows exactly where it's at. Take the [`EJBContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html) for example: supplying contextual information to the EJB. Again, in a container, nothing is hidden

Comment: If you're that interested in tracing its path, you can [grepcode](http://www.grepcode.com/search/usages?type=type&id=repository.jboss.org%24nexus%24content%24repositories%24releases@org.jboss.javaee%24jboss-ejb-api@3.0.0.GA_SP1@javax%24ejb@TimerService&k=u) it yourself. You'll notice a lot of references to proxies and delegates - the bread and butter of a DI container. It's really elementary and boring

Comment: "It's really elementary and boring." I don't know about that, @kolossus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implementation-defined, but there are at least two plausible implementation strategies:

1. When the EJB container injects the TimerService into a bean instance, the TimerService could be bound to that EJB component, so when the timer needs to fire, it knows how to locate an instance and invoke the timeout method.
2. When an EJB invokes a method, it could push metadata about the current EJB component and method onto a ThreadLocal, and when methods are invoked on the TimerService, it locates the current EJB component and creates timers based on that.

Comment: Thanks Brett. This answer my question, particularly "It's implementation defined". If I really want to know how Glassfish does it, I can read the source code myself. Your suggestions for how it might be done will help me read the code.

Answer (score 0):

According to §13.2 of the EJB Specification:

> Timers can be created for stateless session beans, singleton session beans, message-driven beans[88].
>   Timers cannot be created for stateful session beans[89].

The answer to your question for singleton session beans is self evident.

For stateless session beans, it makes no difference which bean instance is invoked as they have no state. The same applies to message driven beans.

Comment: Sorry Steve, my question was unclear. I didn't mean "Which bean from a pool of stateless beans", I meant "Which bean _at all_". I can call `timerService.createSingleActionTimer` from a dozen _different_ stateless bean types, but how does the timer know which callback to call since we don't provide a reference to the bean that invoked it?